# Perl not finding data files

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that is refusing to see existing data files.  When I take the code and isolate in a test perl script it works fine but in the main perl script it can't find anything.

Code looks like this:

```
use Cwd qw(cwd);

my $dir = cwd;
print STDERR "gen-decsplecs : dir $dir : file $ARGV[0]\n";

if (-e $ARGV[0]) {
    print STDERR "gen-declspecs : File Exists : $ARGV[0]\n";
} else {
    print STDERR "gen-declspecs : File does not exist : $ARGV[0]\n";
}

if (-e "C:/Users/walter/Documents/Projects/agar-1.5.0/ada-core/ctxt.h") {
    print STDERR "gen-declspecs : File Exists : C:/Users/walter/Documents/Projects/agar-1.5.0/ada-core/ctxt.h\n";
} else {
    print STDERR "gen-declspecs : File does not exist : C:/Users/walter/Documents/Projects/agar-1.5.0/ada-core/ctxt.h\n";
}

open(F, $ARGV[0]) || die "$ARGV[0]: $!";
```

This prints :

```
gen-decsplecs : dir C:/Users/walter/Documents/Projects/agar-1.5.0 : file './ada-core/ctxt.h'
gen-declspecs : File does not exist : './ada-core/ctxt.h'
gen-declspecs : File Exists : C:/Users/walter/Documents/Projects/agar-1.5.0/ada-core/ctxt.h
'./ada-core/ctxt.h': No such file or directory at mk/gen-declspecs.pl line 93.
gen-declspecs.pl failed
```

So my question is if the code is executing fomr directory :

C:/Users/walter/Documents/Projects/agar-1.5.0

And is looking for file :

./ada-core/ctxt.h

Why does it not exist on the relative path when the full pathed file :

C:/Users/walter/Documents/Projects/agar-1.5.0/ada-core/ctxt.h

does exist? Especially when I have copied the perl to a test script and it does work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line:

```
print STDERR "gen-declspecs : File does not exist : $ARGV[0]\n";
```

(which doesn't include single-quotes) is printing this output:

```
gen-declspecs : File does not exist : './ada-core/ctxt.h'
```

(which does), then that means your `$ARGV[0]` starts and ends with spurious single-quotes. `-e` isn't going to strip those out; for all it knows, maybe you really are interested in a folder named `'.` that contains a folder named `ada-core` that contains a file named `ctxt.h'`!

To fix this, you need to run your script correctly; don't put spurious single-quotes in the arguments to it.

(If you're coming from a Unix-like environment, you need to be aware that the default Windows shell does not use the same quoting rules at all.)

Comment: You're right!  gen-declspecs.pl was being called by a line of code : my @o = readpipe("perl mk/gen-declspecs.pl '$file'"); Which means it should never have worked!!!  But I have download this AGAR script dozens of times and run it successfully. Why has this problem only raised it's head now?